# Asynchronously swap section of html in ASP.Net MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

In ASP.Net MVC 3 I have a Controller and View with a portion of the view's html in a `<div>` whose text I would like to swap out, depending on some action-- a button press, for instance.

Assuming my view has two `<div>s,` the top being the part I'd like to swap out based on an input element in the lower `<div>` being selected, what is a good way to asynchronously do this?  jQuery and ajax are welcome for the task though not required.

[edit] I should have mentioned originally, I'd like to render the content of the asynchronous  by calling a partial view or something similar.  Unfortunately I'm a little new to that and was hoping for quick guidance on how (if?) to call a partial view using ajax or other such techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively simple.

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('div#id').html('the new html');" />
```

where id is the id you have assigned to your div.  Or you can use any other selector to chose the correct div.

Examples here: http://api.jquery.com/html/